# How to get the value of a div in AutoIt?

Tags: html, web, autoit

In this case I want to get a specific value of the last div from this list:

```
<div id="past">
    <div class="ball ball-8" data-rollid="242539">11</div>
    <div class="ball ball-8" data-rollid="242540">11</div>
    <div class="ball ball-1" data-rollid="242541">3</div>
    <div class="ball ball-8" data-rollid="242542">11</div>
    <div class="ball ball-1" data-rollid="242543">5</div>
    <div class="ball ball-1" data-rollid="242544">2</div>
    <div class="ball ball-1" data-rollid="242545">7</div>
    <div class="ball ball-8" data-rollid="242546">14</div>
    <div class="ball ball-1" data-rollid="242547">4</div>
    <div class="ball ball-1" data-rollid="242548">3</div>
</div>
```

I just want to get the outerText from the last entry of this block. In this case it would be 3 with `rollid="242548"`.
How could I get this value?
I tried:

```
$lasts = _IETagNameGetCollection($create, "div")
    For $last In $lasts
    If String($last.id) = "past"  And String($last.innerText) = "242548" Then
        $get = _IEGe
        MsgBox(0,"","")
    $outer = $last.outerText
    GUICtrlSetData( $labellast, $outer)
    EndIf
    Next
```

but it doesn't work.
Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this

```
$past = _IEGetObjById($oIE,"past" )
$lasts = _IETagNameGetCollection($past, "div")

For $last In $lasts
    If StringInStr($last.outerHtml, "242548") Then
        $outer = $last.outerText
        GUICtrlSetData( $labellast, $outer)
    EndIf
Next
```

Comment: Does not work for me :(  The Problem is that there is to less information isnt it?

Comment: @Zoetrope try now.

Comment: Thank you! This worked for me :) didnt know the StringinStr :D

Comment: Glad to hear that @Zoetrope . Feel free to select the answer.

Comment: Select? Do you mean upvote? - I did that but it says i need at least 15 Reputation doing this xD im new to this Site :D